# Как сделать запрос к базе и вывести определенные столбцы?

Tags: node.js

Ситуация такая. В базе есть столбец с айдишниками. Т.е там может быть одно число например 5, а может быть два, например 4,5
Как сделать так, что бы при запросе к базе и поиску по значению 5 - он цеплял и тот столбик, в котором несколько чисел.

```
otd.findAll({where:{
    Id:request.body.data},
    raw: true
  }).then(otd=>{
    if(!otd.length){
      response.json(nonOtd);
      return console.log(nonOtd);
    }
```

Сейчас он ищет только исключительно запросы с 1 числом.

Comment: какая orm то хоть? тут не экстрасенсы)

Comment: Извиняюсь mysql, с базой работаю через sequelize